# simple string manipulation in python: extract required number

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

This is simple string manipulation in python:

```
string = '<longitude>-170.794865296</longitude>'
```

How can i extract `-170.794865296`?
Looking for simple and easy way.

Comment: Is this a part of an xml file? How did you get the string?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html regular expressions should do the trick.

Comment: This is one element of my list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]`

No need to import anything

Comment: +1 I personally like this solution. I'm sure is pretty efficient and if all strings are that simple, this is a very straightforward way to do the job. Don't know why the downvote...

Comment: -0.  If the string isn't what you expect this can fail silently and the bug will be hidden or hard to trace.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> s = '<longitude>-170.794865296</longitude>'
>>> etree.fromstring(s).text
'-170.794865296'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
print re.findall(r'[-0-9.]+', '<longitude>-170.794865296</longitude>')
```

Comment: +1, but please fix for the missing negative sign.  Normally, you should not use regex to parse tagged data, but if you are just pulling some tagged numbers it should fine.  Anything more complicated should be done with a parser (like `xml.etree.ElementTree`).

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are all formatted using the `'<longitude>...</longitude>'` tag, then you could just use string slicing:

```
start = len('<longitude>')
end = -len('</longitude>')
print float('<longitude>-170.48738723</longitude>'[start:end])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using parse module

```
$ pip install parse
```

to impress you by brevity:

```
>>> from parse import parse
>>> parse("<lon>{:f}</lon>", "<lon>-170.794865296</lon>").fixed[0]
-170.794865296
```

to explain it step by step

```
>>> from parse import parse
>>> text = '<lon>-170.794865296</lon>'
>>> templ = "<lon>{:f}</lon>"
>>> res = parse(templ, text)
>>> res
<Result (-170.794865296,) {}>
>>> res.fixed[0]
-170.794865296
>>> type(res.fixed[0])
float
```

assign values to dictionary keys:

```
>>> parse("<lon>{pnt_lat:f}</lon>", "<lon>-170.794865296</lon>").named["pnt_lat"]
-170.794865296
```